# How to get GitHub repo "Views" using Octokit.net?

Tags: c#, github, github-api, octokit.net

How do I get the # of "Views" from GitHub repo using Octokit? I looked through their documentation and didn't see anything related to views.

Comment: What do you mean by the number of "views"? How many people have looked at a repository? How many are watching it? Or something else?

Comment: @kfb how many people have looked at a repository.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is currently providing a preview of the [Repository Traffic API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/traffic) that will allow you to get this information using [the Views endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/traffic/#views).

Be aware that during the preview period, you will need to pass:

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.spiderman-preview
```

in your HTTP headers. It doesn't look like Octokit.NET currently supports this API natively, so you will have to construct the HTTP request yourself.